# SQL Server 2005: Call a stored procedure from a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, where-clause

I need to make a SELECT with a call of a stored procedure in the WHERE clause.
It should be something like that....

SELECT distinct top 10 i.x, d.droit 
FROM v_droit d, v_info i
WHERE d.nomdroit='yy'
      AND i.id<>2
      AND (select val from (exec up_droits(i.x, d.droit)) <>3

But it does not work...
Any idea?

Don't say to replace the stored procedure with a function because is not possible to use the existing code in a function. So the function is not a valid option. I really need to be able to use a stored procedure

Comment: Please update the question (title, description, and tags) to be specific about which particular SQL server you're talking about. There are significant differences in this regard.

Comment: Assume you mean WHERE, not WITH (as mentioned in the question body).

Comment: What does your stored procedure do?

Comment: It has some complex algorithm that creates a query which is executed to verify some access rights. It uses also the stored procedure sp_executesql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is achieved by first executing the stored procedure, capturing the output into a #temp table or a @tabel variable, then running your query against the table. Something like this:

```
declare @droits_table (val ,... );
insert into @droits_table
exec up_droits(param, param);
SELECT distinct top 10 i.x, d.droit FROM v_droit d, v_info i WHERE d.nomdroit='yy' AND i.id<>2 AND (select val from @droits) <>3
```

Of course this will not work for you because the up_droits needs the i.x and d.droit parameters from the query. This indicates that your stored procedure should probably be a a view or table valued function.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but, make it a **table valued function** rather than stored procedure.

Eg:

```
Scalar - SELECT id, name FROM test WHERE id < (SELECT dbo.mytestfunction())
Table - SELECT id, name FROM test WHERE id = (SELECT col1 from dbo.mytestfunction())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The content of the WHERE clause must be a [search expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason that the code doesn't work as a function because it modifies some data? If so, then you're out of luck, functions used in where clauses must be immutable.

If the stored procedure doesn't modify any data, you may be able to wrap it inside of a function.

Comment: No, it does not modify data, but it has to execute a query that is constructed dynamically so it has to be executed with sp_executesql.
Also, this stored procedure calls another stored procedure that has 3 output parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server I don't think you can do what you propose.

But one thing you can do is build dynamic queries, but be careful doing it because they open up many interesting problemareas.

The syntax is :

```
EXEC @<query>
```

But anotherthing you can do, which is probably much better for you, is to make the up_droits function deliver it's results in a temp table, if you select into a #table it is temporary for the duration of your function/procedure scope

```
declare procedure up_droits() as
select val .. into #temp
```

So what you do is create a procedure

```
create procedure Top10FromDroit
begin
  exec up_droits
  SELECT distinct top 10 i.x, d.droit FROM v_droit d, v_info i WHERE d.nomdroit='yy' AND i.id2 AND (select val from (#temp) 3
```

Hopefully that will give you the results you want to achieve.

If at first you don't succeed, code around it^^

Answer (score 0):

Could anyone of you explain reasons for executing dynamic SQl inside stored procedure. I know very few situations when you need them - but really very few. 99.9% (or 999 of a 1000) of execute strings could be rewritten as normal sql statements with parameters.

The very same is with Selects that have functions inside select or where clauses.

Try to think about your sets of data, not about procedural ways how to solve it.

Comment: Metaprogramming: If you have e. g. in one table the name of a table and the columns of this table that a select should return - and you want to implement the logic in SQL, as e. g. several applications access the (dynamic) result set.

Comment: @RiverC for recursive tree traversal, you do not need dynamic SQL. You can use recursive CTEs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx