# How to execute stored procedure in where statement

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures

If I have a stored procedures that takes a '`id`' and return '`age`' . suppose its name is `getAge`
and I want to use this stored procedure to get age , given the `id`

If I have a query such this :

```
select id, age where age > ( getAge id)
```

How to do that ?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943516/sql-server-2005-call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-where-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server

```
Declare @t table(age int)
insert into @t
EXEC procedure_name

select id, age where age > (select age from @t)
```