# Calling stored procedure in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to call my sp in my query but there is 2 errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT O.OrderId
  ,O.Number
  ,O.Creation
  ,(SELECT Name + ' ' + Surname FROM [User] WHERE UserId = (SELECT CreatedBy FROM [User] WHERE UserId = O.UserId) ) AS OrderOwner
  ,(SELECT Name + ' ' + Surname FROM [User] WHERE UserId = O.UserId )AS Customer
  ,(SELECT Telephone1 FROM [User]  WHERE UserId =  O.UserId) AS Telephone
  ,(SELECT CASE IsActive WHEN 1 THEN 'Indirimli' WHEN 0 THEN 'Indirimsiz' END AS Indirim FROM [User] WHERE UserId = O.UserId) AS Discount
  ,(SELECT CASE IsActive
     WHEN 0
     THEN 

         (SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Product WHERE ProductId IN( SELECT ProductId FROM OrderProduct WHERE OrderId = O.OrderId )) 
    WHEN 1
    THEN
    EXEC USP_CalculatePrice 70

    END AS Price
   FROM [User] WHERE UserId = O.UserID) AS Price

  ,O.Description
  ,O.Status 
  FROM
  [Order] AS O
  WHERE O.Status = 0
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Stored procedures don't work like that. The only way you can get a stored procedure to interact with a query is doing `INSERT ... EXEC`. It's unclear what that procedure does... maybe a table-valued function would be more appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005: Call a stored procedure from a WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943516/sql-server-2005-call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-where-clause)

Comment: Can you please explain us what ups_calculatePrice does, so we can give you the best possible answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call stored procedures within an existing `select` statement. What you want is [user defined scalar function](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions) (as opposed to a table function or built in function).

Depending on what you're really trying to do, a user defined table function could apply. In that case, you'd make a function that returns a table and then you could join to it. They're a bit like views but accept parameters.